# Android Maps v 2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to integrate Android Maps version 2 in to my App.
I have started with example provided at this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code

I am getting a Authorization Failure Exception.

Below text is from logcat

```
01-30 22:51:25.953: D/GestureDetector(5418): Change mBiggerTouchSlopSquare from 400 to 729
01-30 22:51:26.003: D/dalvikvm(5418): GC_CONCURRENT freed 793K, 19% free 3832K/4707K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-30 22:51:26.023: I/global(5418): call createSocket() return a new socket.
01-30 22:51:26.063: D/libEGL(5418): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-30 22:51:26.083: D/libEGL(5418): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
01-30 22:51:26.083: D/libEGL(5418): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
01-30 22:51:26.083: D/libEGL(5418): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
01-30 22:51:26.103: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5418): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
01-30 22:51:26.123: D/memalloc(5418): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x53a22000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:93
01-30 22:51:26.143: D/OpenGLRenderer(5418): Enabling debug mode 0
01-30 22:51:26.173: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5418): <ConfigWindowMatch:2098>: Format RGBX_8888.
01-30 22:51:26.203: D/memalloc(5418): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x543d7000 size:3391488 offset:0 fd:97
01-30 22:51:26.243: D/memalloc(5418): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54c96000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:100
01-30 22:51:26.293: D/memalloc(5418): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x55156000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:103
01-30 22:51:26.323: D/dalvikvm(5418): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1359K, 31% free 4020K/5795K, paused 17ms
****01-30 22:51:26.333: E/Google Maps Android API(5418): Authorization failure.****
01-30 22:51:26.373: D/memalloc(5418): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x55560000 size:3391488 offset:0 fd:106
01-30 22:51:26.393: D/memalloc(5418): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x558ac000 size:3391488 offset:0 fd:109
```

Can someone please provide me information on how to resolve this ?
I am sorry if this is a trivial question, i am new to Android app development.

Android Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.googlemapsdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.googlemapsdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="my api key"/>
    </application>
     <permission
          android:name="com.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your problem solved or not???

Comment: Can you add your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

That suggests that either you do not have a valid Maps V2 API key in your manifest, or that the API key was not configured with the correct APK signing key fingerprint or Android application package name. Obtaining an API key is covered in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Answer (score 0):

Create an API key . Place it in your Manifest file -

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
```

Please read the section - **Obtaining the API Key** from the link -
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps for getting map:

1.You should get a `API key`  by using this command  in `Command prompt` Change directory to `Bin folder of your Jdk`  and use this command there `keytool -v -list -keystore C:\Users\Ponmani\.android\debug.keystore`.By using this you will get an `MD5 fingerprint`.

2.By using this `MD5 fingerprint`.  You have to `signup for getting API key`.

3.Make sure that you are using `Google API's` device

4.In `Manifest file` set permission for `"INTERNET"` And `GOOGLE MAPS`. If you followed these correctly means surely map will work.